# plot of same multiple values against different y values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a matrix with zeros and ones. I want to make a plot to see which part has which specification. I made a little example about how my matrix is looking like. Currently I just do that, but I know this is wrong and could not figure out how I can plot the Products on the x axis and the Specs on the y axis ( or different way). I want to see how my distribution of the specs is for all my parts. I tried it with scatter plot but it does not work, since the number of x and y does not match. If the question is not clear enough, please ask me for correction, since my english is not the best. I do not want a whole code, I could not find an example for my case thats why I asked this question.

```
#after my import I filled the NaN with zeros
data=data.fillna(0)
pn=data.iloc[:,0]
specs=data.iloc[:,1:6]
plt.scatter(specs,pn)
```

[image]

Update:

What would help would be an heatmap or something where I can see the distribution of how often one specification occurs, like in the picture below. [image]

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: @cheersmate I included my try

Comment: Do you have a sketch or example of the kind of plot you are trying to make?

Comment: @evan I updated it, those would be me ideas, but if you have a better option feel free to tell that to me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started. Thanks for updating your question. I leaned heavily on `seaborn`, `pandas`, and `numpy`.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(2, size=100).reshape(10,10)
ax = sns.heatmap(data)
```

This creates a 10x10 array of 1s and 0s.

```
[[0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]]
```

Here's the heatmap:

[image: heatmap]

You can also sum using numpy or pandas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sum(axis=1).plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: pandas bar plot]

Comment: that looks great for the beginning, I will work from there!